# Is there a way to have a th header cell tag in xPages?

Tags: xpages

Is there a way to have a th header cell tag in xPages?   I have searched everywhere for this and found only one question with not answer.

Is it possible?  I tried using xp:th but I get an unknown tag error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should also be possible using the tagName attribute introduced in Domino 8.5.3.

E.g.

```
<xp:panel tagName="th"></xp:panel>
```

or

```
<xp:text value="I am TH" tagName="th" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use pass through HTML

<th> </th>

Comment: there is no such term in xPages

Comment: It can be simulated using a computed field.

Comment: Why is there no th tag  in xpages?  Seems this would be the better way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with stwissel. I build my tables with "standard" html and use XPages controls inside the table. Doing so, you can also use HTML elements that are not available in XPages, like

```
        <table style="table-layout:fixed;" class="fixedTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="60" />
            <col width="190" />
        </colgroup>
```

Using the xp:tag with the tagname attribute might be a more consistent way, but has some unneccessary overhead.

Comment: I tend to do what you do. xp-components can be intermingled with standard html. If I need show-when on a cell or a row, I use xp-component. E.g. <table><tr><td>content</td></tr><xp:tr><td>show when content</td></xp:tr></table>